# Can't find Audiofile in the Filebrowser

Tags: import, audio, file-browser

I've written a script which creates an an audio visualizer.

The python console gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I'm not able to find the audio file in Blender.

As it didn't work within the script I tried to import the audio via the File Browser, but as I tried to import the audio file from the File Browser, the File Browser also didn't show me the audio file at the location it was supposed to be at.

I'm sure it has to be Blender. I've found the file in every other application. (VLC, Windows Media player)

Comment: What type of file?  What format/codec?  Mp3, WAV, Flac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. 
I entered the error into google and found the solution. I used backslashes instead of just slashes. This was the cause of my error.

Sorry for waisting your time. I should have googled the error right away.

AliSot2000